# ply lex yacc как найти закрывающую кавычку?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, lex, yacc

Делаю лексер для юридического текста. Вот пример:

```
    9) дополнить статьей 4211 следующего содержания:
"Статья 4211.   Особенности выполнения комплексных кадастровых работ, финансируемых за счет внебюджетных средств

1. Комплексные кадастровые работы, финансируемые за счет внебюджетных средств, могут быть выполнены в границах:
1) территории ведения гражданами садоводства или огородничества для собственных нужд;
2) территории, используемой гаражным потребительским кооперативом или товариществом собственников жилья, а также членами таких кооператива или товарищества;
3) единого, неразрывного элемента планировочной структуры или совокупности таких смежных элементов, расположенных в границах одного муниципального образования.
2. Комплексные кадастровые работы в границах территорий, указанных в части 1 настоящей статьи, выполняются в отношении всех объектов комплексных кадастровых работ независимо от границ кадастрового деления.
3. При выполнении комплексных кадастровых работ, финансируемых за счет внебюджетных средств, получение сведений Единого государственного реестра недвижимости, государственного адресного реестра и иных необходимых для выполнения таких работ сведений, материалов или документов осуществляется исполнителем комплексных кадастровых работ самостоятельно, если иное 
не установлено договором подряда на выполнение указанных работ.
4. Заказчик комплексных кадастровых работ, финансируемых 
за счет внебюджетных средств, в течение десяти рабочих дней со дня заключения договора подряда на выполнение комплексных кадастровых работ обеспечивает информирование граждан и юридических лиц 
о начале выполнения таких комплексных кадастровых работ путем:
1) размещения извещения о начале выполнения комплексных кадастровых работ на своем официальном сайте в информационно-телекоммуникационной сети "Интернет" (при наличии официального сайта);
2) направления извещения о начале выполнения комплексных кадастровых работ в орган, уполномоченный на утверждение карты-плана территории;
3) размещения или обеспечения размещения извещения о начале выполнения комплексных кадастровых работ на информационных щитах в границах территории выполнения комплексных кадастровых работ.
5. Орган, уполномоченный на утверждение карты-плана территории, в течение пяти рабочих дней со дня получения извещения о начале выполнения комплексных кадастровых работ, финансируемых за счет внебюджетных средств, обеспечивает информирование граждан 
и юридических лиц о начале выполнения таких комплексных кадастровых работ путем:
1) размещения извещения о начале выполнения комплексных кадастровых работ в печатном средстве массовой информации и сетевом издании, в которых осуществляется обнародование (официальное опубликование) его правовых актов, а также на своем официальном сайте 
в информационно-телекоммуникационной сети "Интернет" (при наличии официального сайта);
2) размещения или обеспечения размещения извещения о начале выполнения комплексных кадастровых работ на своих информационных щитах;
3) направления извещения о начале выполнения комплексных кадастровых работ в орган местного самоуправления поселения, 
на территории которого выполняются комплексные кадастровые работы, для размещения на официальном сайте поселения в информационно-телекоммуникационной сети "Интернет" (при наличии официального сайта) и на информационных щитах органа местного самоуправления такого поселения;
4) направления извещения в орган регистрации прав для размещения на его официальном сайте в информационно-телекоммуникационной сети "Интернет" и отображения сведений 
о территории выполнения комплексных кадастровых работ 
на кадастровых картах, в том числе публичных кадастровых картах.
6. Заказчик комплексных кадастровых работ, финансируемых 
за счет внебюджетных средств, после рассмотрения проекта карты-плана территории направляет его в орган, уполномоченный на утверждение карты-плана территории, для последующего направления 
в согласительную комиссию.
7. Орган, уполномоченный на утверждение карты-плана 
территории, в течение пяти календарных дней со дня получения 
проекта карты-плана территории направляет его в согласительную комиссию.
8. Согласование местоположения границ земельных участков при выполнении комплексных кадастровых работ, финансируемых за счет внебюджетных средств, осуществляется в порядке, установленном статьей 4210 настоящего Федерального закона.";
    10) часть 3 статьи 45 признать утратившей силу.
```

Я нахожу открывающую кавычку после слов 'содержания:', у меня это токен OQUOTE. Дальше идет произвольный текст, в котором может быть все, включая кавычки. Как мне распознать, что кавычка перед словами '10) часть 3 статьи 45 признать утратившей силу.' является закрывающей кавычкой блока, а не относится к самому содержимому блока?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно заякориться к тому, что после кавычки идёт новая строка и новый блок начинается с 4 пробелов:

```regex
[ ]{4}\d+\.?\d*\).*\n"(.*)";\n[ ]{4}\d+\.?\d*\)
```

Пробуйте:

https://regex101.com/r/ZSRewF/1